# Prove that for any $x\in(a,b)$, $[D_f(x)]_r$ is a closed interval.

Tags: real-analysis

(a) Let $f: [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.

For $x\in(a,b)$ define
$[D_f(x)]_r:=\{M\in\mathbb{R} | \exists (x_n)_{n=1}^\infty\subset(x,b), \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x,\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(x)-f(x_n)}{x-x_n}=M\}$

Prove  that  for  any $x\in(a,b)$,  $[D_f(x)]_r$ is  a  closed  interval.   (Possibly  unbounded  or  a singleton set).

I am having trouble with how I should approach this quesiton. Any suggestions?

PS: this is a homework problem

Comment: A well-posted and challenging question. Why closed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x\in(a,b)$ be fixed. Firstly, observe that $[D_{f}(x)]_{r}$
is equal to $[D_{f}(x)]_{r}=\{y\in[-\infty,\infty]\mid\exists(x_{n})\subseteq(x,b), x_{1}>x_{2}>\ldots>x,\,x_{n}\rightarrow x,\frac{f(x_{n})-f(x)}{x_{n}-x}\rightarrow y\}$

because if $(x_{n})$ is a sequence in $(x,b)$ such that $x_{n}\rightarrow x$
and $\frac{f(x_{n})-f(x)}{x_{n}-x}\rightarrow y$, we can always pass
to a suitable subsequence $(x_{n_{k}})$ such that $x_{n_{1}}>x_{n_{2}}>\ldots>x$.

Let $m=\liminf_{y\rightarrow x+}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$ and $M=\limsup_{y\rightarrow x+}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$.
Clearly $[D_{f}(x)]_{r}\subseteq[m,M]$ by the very definition of
liminf and limsup. We go to show that $[m,M]\subseteq[D_{f}(x)]_{r}$.
If $m=M$, the right-hand derivative $f_{r}'(x)$ exists and equals
to $m=M$. In this case, obviously $[D_{f}(x)]_{r}=\{f'_{r}(x)\}$.

Suppose that $m<M$. Obviously, we have $m,M\in [D_{f}(x)]_{r}$.
Let $\xi\in(m,M)$ be arbitrary. Choose $c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$m<c<\xi<d<M$. Choose strictly
decreasing sequences $(x_{n})$ and $(y_{n})$ in $(x,b)$ such that
$x_{n}\rightarrow x$, $y_{n}\rightarrow x$, $\frac{f(x_{n})-f(x)}{x_{n}-x}\rightarrow m$
and $\frac{f(y_{n})-f(x)}{y_{n}-x}\rightarrow M$. By passing to subsequences,
without loss of generality, we may assume that $\frac{f(x_{n})-f(x)}{x_{n}-x}<c$
and $\frac{f(y_{n})-f(x)}{y_{n}-x}>d$ for all
$n$. By further passing to suitable subsequences, we may assume that
$x_{n+1}<y_{n+1}<x_{n}<y_{n}$ for all $n$. Define $\theta_{n}:[x_{n},y_{n}]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,
$\theta_{n}(t)=\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}$. Note that $\theta_{n}$ is
continuous and $\theta_{n}(x_{n})<c<\xi<d<\theta_{n}(y_{n})$.
By intermediate value theorem, there exists $z_{n}\in(x_{n},y_{n})$
such that $\theta_{n}(z_{n})=\xi$. Since $x_{n}<z_{n}<y_{n}$, it
is clear that $(z_{n})$ is strictly decreasing and $z_{n}\rightarrow x$.
Moreover, $\frac{f(z_{n})-f(x)}{z_{n}-x}=\xi$ for each $n$ and hence
trivially $\frac{f(z_{n})-f(x)}{z_{n}-x}\rightarrow\xi$. This shows
that $\xi\in[D_{f}(x)]_{r}$.

Comment: For the second part, consider $f(x)=|x|$, then $D_f(0)=\{-1,1\}$.